# Como obtener todas las recetas que tengan todos sus productos en stock

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
Recipes
| id           | name        |
| ------------ | ------------|
| 1            | recipe_1    |
| 2            | recipe_2    |
| 3            |recipe_3     |
```

Ingredients

```
| id   | name          | stock |
|------| ------------- |-------|
| 1    | ingredient_1  |  25
| 2    | ingredient_2  |  60
|3     | ingredient_3  |  10
```

ingredient_recipe

```
|id|recipe_id|ingredient_id|quantity|
|--|---------|-------------|--------|
|1 |1        |1            |30
|2 |1        |2            |5
|3 |1        |3            |5
|4 |2        |2            |10
|5 |3        |2            |20
|6 |3        |3            |30
```

necesito obtener todas las recipes en donde el stock de todos sus ingredients, sea mayor a lo que se dispone en quantity de la tabla ingredient_recipe

He intentando con la siguiente consulta:

```
select r.id, r.name
from recipes as r
join ingredient_product as ip on ip.product_id = r.id
join ingredients as i on i.id = ip.ingredient_id and i.stock > ip.quantity
group by r.id
```

pero me muestra todas las recipes que tienen al menos 1 ingredient_product que cumpla la condición, y necesito que si alguna no cumple no lo liste.

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué has intentado? Edita, por favor, la pregunta y añade la consulta con lo que hayas intentado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la información que buscas de manera sencilla con SQL, yo primero le daría una vuelta de tuerca a la idea.

Y es que otra forma de expresar lo que buscas es:

Quiero obtener las recetas para las que **no haya** al menos un ingrediente cuya existencia sea menor a la cantidad de la receta.

Y es que al no existir ninguno que no tenga la existencia suficiente, en realidad estamos validando que **todos** tengan existencia suficiente.

Con esto en mente, valiéndonos de la cláusula *not exists*, la consulta se vuelve trivial:

```
select id, name
  from recipes
 where not exists (select 1
                     from ingredient_recipe
                          inner join ingredients on ingredients.id = ingredient_recipe.ingredient_id
                    where ingredient_recipe.recipe_id = recipes.id
                      and ingredients.stock < ingredient_recipe.quantity
                  )
```

Para que esto funcione, sin embargo, es imprescindible que haya una llave foránea entre `ingredient_recipe` e `ingredient`, ya que si hay líneas huérfanas, habría que hacer ajustes.

Comment: en la ejecución que hice con tu código también me dio como uno de los resultados, la receta tres('recipe_3' ) y el ingrediente 3 tiene 3 en stock y la receta requiere 30. es cuestión mía=

Comment: Si lo que dices es cierto, la sub-consulta devolvería el registro, ya que 3 es menor que 30, y por tanto, excluiría esa receta del conjunto de resultados final.

Comment: @Victor, he preparado este fiddle con tus datos y mi solución y devuelve solo la `recipe_2`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c6a77/1/0

Comment: vale entonces, copie mal yo tu respuesta. perdón :D

Comment: Diría que entre copiar y pegar, y copiar mal, es preferible la primera. Aunque lo mejor, es leer con atención para entender la idea, leer la sentencia y luego, escribirla por uno mismo, pues eso te acerca más al aprendizaje. Me alegra que te dieras cuenta que es correcta la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

primero que nada cabe recalcar que esta desde luego no es la respuesta más óptima,
pero sí una que funciona,

para hacer pruebas con tu base de datos, me hizo falta replicarla, y para no instalar postgres, usé sqlite, con el siguiente esquema. pero la funcionailidad es la misma.

(es común poner el nombre de las tablas en singular)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE recipe(id integer primary key, name text not null);
INSERT INTO recipe VALUES(1,'recipe_1');
INSERT INTO recipe VALUES(2,'recipe_2');
INSERT INTO recipe VALUES(3,'recipe_3');
CREATE TABLE ingredient(id integer primary key not null, name text not null, stock integer not null);
INSERT INTO ingredient VALUES(1,'ingredient_1',25);
INSERT INTO ingredient VALUES(2,'ingredient_2',60);
INSERT INTO ingredient VALUES(3,'ingredient_3',10);
CREATE TABLE ingredient_recipe(id integer unique not null, recipe integer not null, ingredient integer not null, quantity integer, PRIMARY KEY(id, recipe, ingredient), constraint fk_recipe FOREIGN KEY(recipe) references recipe(id), CONSTRAINT fk_ingredient FOREIGN key(ingredient) REFERENCES ingredient(id));
INSERT INTO ingredient_recipe VALUES(1,1,1,30);
INSERT INTO ingredient_recipe VALUES(2,1,2,5);
INSERT INTO ingredient_recipe VALUES(3,1,3,5);
INSERT INTO ingredient_recipe VALUES(4,2,2,10);
INSERT INTO ingredient_recipe VALUES(5,3,2,20);
INSERT INTO ingredient_recipe VALUES(6,3,3,30);
COMMIT;
```

y para sacar las recetas que si se pueden cocinar es el siguente comando.

la respuesta de jachguate, parece que también regresa la 'recipe_3' por lo que no sé si hice mal algo yo al copiar su código.

Lo primero que hay que hacer es

```
select  recipe.id , 
recipe.name as recipe, 
ingredient.name as ingredient, 
(stock - ingredient_recipe.quantity>0) as availability  
from recipe join ingredient_recipe on ingredient_recipe.recipe = recipe.id 
join ingredient on ingredient_recipe.ingredient = ingredient.id;
```

ver cuáles de los ingredientes que tienes en stock son suficientes para hacer qué receta.

luego concatené el número de conjuntos de ingredientes necesarios para cada receta y por último junté y conté el número de conjuntos disponibles que tenía.

con esta tabla intermedia solo era cuestión de seleccionar donde la resta de ambas sumas de conjuntos fuera mayor o igual a zero.

```
select recipe from 
(select recipe, count(availability) as available_ingredients, ingredients_needed 
from (select * from (select * from (select  recipe.id , recipe.name as recipe, ingredient.name as ingredient, (stock - ingredient_recipe.quantity>=0) as availability  
from recipe join ingredient_recipe on ingredient_recipe.recipe = recipe.id join ingredient on ingredient_recipe.ingredient = ingredient.id) mid join 
(select recipe, count(recipe) as ingredients_needed from (select  recipe.id , recipe.name as recipe, ingredient.name as ingredient, (stock - ingredient_recipe.quantity>=0) as availability  
from recipe join ingredient_recipe on ingredient_recipe.recipe = recipe.id join ingredient on ingredient_recipe.ingredient = ingredient.id) group by recipe) new on new.recipe = mid.recipe) 
where availability  = true) group by recipe) where available_ingredients>=ingredients_needed;
```